# Can't downgrade Linux kernel: not enough free disk space

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, drivers, system-recovery, yaourt

I'm stuck in an archiso/chrooted environment (booting from a USB flash drive) because my Wi-Fi drivers are incompatible with Linux 4.8.7-1, and cause the system to hang at boot. I'm trying a few things right now:

- First of all, I got rid of the `b43-firmware` via `yaourt -R` after chrooting into my mounted internal hard drive. The uninstall was successful as far as I know; no errors or warnings were raised. I can still access the internet via an Ethernet dongle at this point.

  - Unfortunately, this caused an error where, during boot, after the `grub` menu, I got the following error messages:

    ```
    b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
    b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode29_mimo.fw" not found
    b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware...
    ```
- I'm now trying to downgrade my kernel back to 4.8.6-1, but I'm having some trouble with that too. After chrooting into my mounted root partition (which is about 200GB; about 10GB used), I `cd` into `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` and try to `pacman -U linux-4.8.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz linux-headers-4.8.6-1.pkg.tar.xz`, but for some reason I get these errors:

  ```
  error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
  error: could not determine filesystem mount points
  error: not enough free disk space
  ```

Now, the first error is just plain wrong. `/etc/mtab` is available as a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`; I'm not sure what the second error is even talking about; and the third error is also straight up wrong: a Linux kernel downgrade shouldn't use over 190GB of space.

At this point, I've also tried to reinstall `b43-firmware` via `yaourt` in the `chroot`ed environment, but no matter what package I try to install, I get something along the lines of `target not found`, even when the package shows up via `yaourt -Ss`. It's also worth noting that Yaourt's interactive environment doesn't actually work inside `chroot`.

How can I either:

- Resolve the issues preventing me from downgrading the kernel; or
- Resolve the issues with the wireless drivers which are keeping me from booting?

Comment: Are you sure that `/proc` is bound within your chroot environment? Is getting `strace` in your pre-chroot environment an option? This could maybe show something (although I've never used it in conjunction with chroot; might be a bit tricky)

Answer (score 0):

First solutions you might want to try are:

- installing firmware-b43-installer or b43-fwcutter followed by installing proper firmware
- add blacklist b43 to end of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
- b43.blacklist=yes at kernel commandline in grub start menu, during boot
- rebuilding kernel without support for B43

I have no idea if downgrading kernel is part of Your first question, or separate one (to my understanding you have module in kernel that is using proprietary WiFi firmware that is not part of kernel).

Anyway I agree with TNW's comment that probably after chroot your mounts are not directly accessible. Could You check and update question with `mount`?
And also, maybe you might want to try doing `sudo mount / -o remount,rw`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those worked. I ended up wiping my old arch install, bootstrapping the filesystem again, and I could only downgrade the kernel (and by extension get b43 and alternatives to work) on the new system. I'm still not sure what the root cause of the previous issue was, but unfortunately, I couldn't wait for a proper solution on this hardware. I'll try to recreate the same scenario in a VM in the coming days to try and find a proper solution. Thanks all the same!